# precedence of ~ and ++ in java

Tags: java, operators, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

consider this code snippet

```
int j = 7;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(j));
j = ~j++;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(j));
```

prints

```
111
11111111111111111111111111111000
```

what i am expecting to see

```
111
11111111111111111111111111111001
```

first i thought it might be the precedence of ~ and ++

if the ~ is evaluated before ++ 
the answer will be

```
11111111111111111111111111111001
```

else if the ++ is evaluated before ~

```
11111111111111111111111111110111
```

I searched [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) but I couldn't find the answer.
Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: No one should write code this way.

Comment: Have you tried `j = ~(++j)` and compared?

Comment: Hm... is this defined behaviour at all in Java? You are changing j on both sides of the assignment. I think even if you tried `j=j++` you might get unexpected results. So this isn't really a question of precedence.

Comment: @Axel This is perfectly well-defined behaviour in Java. Somewhat pointless and generally confusing, but definitely well-defined. Java is not really in the business of [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Axel, @Dukeling: I looked it up to be certain, and Dukeling is correct. This ambiguity is resolved by the specification, which provides a specific order of evaluation for assignment operations. The following link shows the order of operations for the outer, `j = ...` assignment operation:

[Java Spec section 15.26.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1)

What I didn't see a clear specification of would be the behaviour of something like:

`j = ++j + j--;`

In this case, is the ++j evaluated before or after the j++? And is it the same in every VM?

Comment: Ah, here it is: [Java Spec section 15.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) The order is strictly left-to-right, and no part of the right starts evaluating before the left is completely finished. I guess that puts a bit of a damper on what sorts of optimizations would be possible :-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget that the '++' post-increment operator returns the value of j *before* the increment happened. That is, if 'j' is 7, then 'j++' sets j to 8, *but returns 7*. ~7 is then the output that you saw, the number ending in three 0 bits.

The '++' post-increment operator can only operate on so-called "L-values". An L-value is a value that actually exists somewhere that code can logically reference -- a variable, or an array element, a parameter or a class field. As soon as you take the value of of an L-value and you apply some numerical operation to it, you get an R-value. R-values are *just* the value, and they don't refer to any persistent storage where a result could be put. You can assign to L-values but not to R-values -- and so if you tried to '++' an R-value, you would get a compile error.

If the '~' operator went first, then you'd be ++-ing an R-value, as in (~j)++. This would not compile. The fact that the code compiles at all means that the precedence is the other way: ~(j++).

Parentheses like this is the simplest way I know of that you can sort out precedence whenever there is any confusion: Just write three test cases:

1. The original way that you're uncertain about.
2. With parentheses forcing one order of operations.
3. With parentheses forcing the other order of operations.

Run it and see whether #2 or #3 produces the same result as #1. :-)

Comment: as u mentioned j = (~j)++ gives compile error 
~(j++) is equivalent to ~j++ since the ++ has higher precedence

Comment: +1 Very nice answer, especially the r-value / l-value mention.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems very brittle. I think that what is happening is that when the expression "~i++" is evaluated the value "~i" is extracted, "i++" is performed and then finally the assignment (overriding the previous value from "i++").

Comment: ~8 is 11111111111111111111111111110111, not 11111111111111111111111111111000.

Edit: I see your edit :-) However, you still have the order backwards. The ++ happens first, but the result of the ++ is 7 not 8.

Comment: Easily confused with -8.  I was confused for a moment and thought this answer was correct.

Comment: Yeah, got confused initially. Should put a little more thought before answering.

Comment: This answer may be *somewhat* accurate, but, if it is, it is unlikely to be understood correctly. Please read [Jonathan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16485411/1711796) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Both operators are right associative second degree operators, but a simple test reveals that it is the `++` executed first and the BITWISE NOT operation the latter.

```
int j = 7, z = 7, k = 7;
z = z++;
z = ~z;
k = ~k++;
j = ~j;
j++;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(z));
// 11111111111111111111111111111000
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(j));
// 11111111111111111111111111111001
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(k));
// 11111111111111111111111111111000
```

Answer (score 1):

Unary operators (`++1`, `--`, `+`, `-`, `~`, `!`) are evaluated from right to left.  Hence `++` is evaluated before `~`.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't do that. There is no reason to bunch up operators like that into one statement, but I realize you weren't really planning to put this into live code and were just experimenting. Try this page for Java operator precedence: http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php

Comment: as mentioned in the link the postfix increment is evaluated before ~ 
then the answer should be 
increment first : 00.....01000
then complement : 11.....10111

Comment: This should've been a comment, unless you actually extract the information required from the link and post it in the answer with an explanation.

Comment: please explain if there is something i didn't notice in the link 
i could extract the the ++ (pre- or postfix increment) has higher precedence than ~ and both of them have right Associativity